# Why does it show (-) instead of (tty1) in my linux console? How can I fix it?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, console

So I clean installed arch Linux today and It's showing (`-`) instead of (`ttyn`) where `n` is the number of the TTY. Is there a way to fix it so that it shows the correct TTY?

Here is a photo of the screen:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsd1K.jpg]

Answer (score 5):

This is a known bug since a few days ago.

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/21919

and is related to https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/issues/1546

> Systemd 250 changed its getty@ unit file in systemd/systemd@b4bf900 to
> call agetty with stdin ("-") port as apparently the kernel could have
> pontentially reset ttys otherwise. This means that any distribution
> running systemd will now not display the tty device name at the login
> prompt, but a dash symbol instead

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought I did something wrong while installing and it was eating me up lol. I assume it's gonna be fixed sooner or later? or do I have to manually fix it?

Comment: No, I guess it will be fixed very quickly. This affects lots of distributions, so in a few days an update of the packages will probably resolve the issue.

Comment: Cool. Thank you again for helping!